# segue not working with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I can't transition to detailViewController for some reasons. It works when i don't use the map with the tableView. Here is the code i am using for the segue and here is the [whole project](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1EPIKZI6a5saTBRTlBYdndyQjQ&usp=sharing)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

        let detailViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController

        detailViewController.Name = self.index

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueID", sender: self.index)
```

--

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if segue.identifier == "segueID" {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
        vc.Name = sender as! [String]
        }
    }
}
```